Difference between TalkBack and Voice Assistant in Android
I'm implementing a ContentDescription in Android. I used setAccessibilityDelegate to change the EditText what is read when the Accessibility Focus moved.
Using TalkBalk, when I move the Accessibility Focus to the EditText, It reads the hint as I modified. However, in former OS just like OS 7.0, when I use a Voice Assistant, It reads differently.
Is there an any way to make TalkBack and Voice Assistant read same?
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(binding.editText, object :
            AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
            override fun performAccessibilityAction(
                host: View,
                action: Int,
                args: Bundle?
            ): Boolean {
                if(action == AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS.id) {
                    binding.editText.contentDescription = word
                }
                return super.performAccessibilityAction(host, action, args)
            }
            })


